# Looking for advice on programs to open huge text files

Tags: text

I have several files which I need to examine I'm currently using ultra edit and it works but I'm looking for something that can deal with a really big file a little better than ultra edit.  It is entirely too slow and crashes a lot.  The sizes of the files are 10+ GB.  I've tried hex editor but it gives me the information in the wrong format. Any suggestions>?

Comment: I think this belongs more on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than here. I think you're more likely to get the answer you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Vim and the [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin for big files I need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) to open file.